# Create network variable to capture observations who are connected through a grouped variable both directly and indirectly in R

Tags: r, networking, social-networking

I have a data frame that includes principals, the schools they worked at and the years they worked there. I would like to create a new variable (network) that represents what comparison "network" they're in. Here, network would take on the same value for any principals who worked in the same school in different years **or** any other principal who worked at another school that a principal from that school also worked at and all the other principals who also worked at that  school **or** any other principal who worked at another school that a principal from that school also worked, and so on. Network can also be defined at the school level, where a network is a set of schools in which every school has had at least one principal transfer to at least one other school in the network during the years in the data.

Essentially, the variable should "connect" any principals who are connected through the schools they have worked at, so that they can eventually be compared to one another in a value-added model. Each principal would have one unique network value.

Here's a (very much so) simplified dataframe to represent the data structure:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

#basic data  
ps <- data.frame(principal = rep(letters[1:5], each = 4), 
                 year=rep(1:4))

recode_if <- function(x, condition, ...) {
  if_else(condition, recode(x, ...), x)
}

#add in schools and then create some variation to demonstrate different ways to connect   
ps <- ps %>%   
  mutate(school = fcase(  
             principal=="a", "fhs",   
             principal=="b", "ghs",   
             principal=="c", "lms",   
             principal=="d", "pms",   
             principal=="e", "ehs",   
             default=NA_character_)) %>%   
  mutate(school = recode_if(school, principal=="b" & year>=2,   
                            "ghs"="lms")) %>%   
  mutate(school = recode_if(school, principal=="c" & year>=2,   
                            "lms"="tms")) %>%   
  mutate(school = recode_if(school, principal=="d" & year>=4,   
                           "pms"="ehs")) %>%   
  mutate(school = recode_if(school, principal=="e" & year>=4,   
                            "ehs" = NA_character_))
```

In the above example, principal a would be in their own network because they haven't worked at any school other than fhs, nor has any other principal in this dataset worked at fhs. Principals b and c would have the same network value, connected through lms. No other principals would be in that network because no one else has worked at ghs, lms, or tms. Principals d and e would be in the same network, connected through ehs.

I've tried exploring the social network analysis world but didn't have much luck, although I've not worked with that type of data before so its possible the answer lies there! I also tried some different looping approaches, but also couldn't get it to work correctly.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using `tidygraph`, a wrapper around `igraph`.

```
# Show all links where two principals worked at same school (incl self-joins)
ps %>%
  left_join(ps, by = "school") %>%
  select(principal.x, principal.y) -> links


library(tidygraph)
links %>% 
  as_tbl_graph(directed = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(group = group_components()) %>%
  activate(nodes) %>%
  data.frame() 


#  name group
#1    a     3
#2    b     1
#3    c     1
#4    d     2
#5    e     2
```